# Trying to send a float value over SPI between 2 Arduinos

Tags: arduino, spi

I am currently trying to send a float value across two Arduinos via SPI. Currently I am working to send a static value of 2.25 across and then read it via the `Serial.println()` command. I would then want to pass a float value from a linear displacement sensor. My end goal is to be able to have the master ask for information, the slave gathers the appropriate data and packages it and then master receives said data and does what it needs with it.

Currently I am getting an error "call of overloaded 'println(byte [7])' is ambiguous" and I am not to sure why I am getting this error. I am currently a mechanical engineering student and I am crash-coursing myself through C/C++. I am not entirely positive about what I am doing. I know that a float is 4 bytes and I am attempting to create a buffer of 7 bytes to store the float and the '\n' char with room to spare. My current code is below.

Master:

```
#include <SPI.h>
void setup() {
  pinMode(SS,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SS,HIGH);
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV4);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(SS,LOW);
  float a = 2.25;
  SPI.transfer(a);
  SPI.transfer('\n');
  digitalWrite(SS,HIGH);
}
```

My slave code is as follows:

```
#include <SPI.h>

byte buf[7];
volatile byte pos = 0;
volatile boolean process_it = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(MISO,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(MISO,LOW);
  SPCR |= _BV(SPE); // SPI Enable, sets this Arduino to Slave
  SPCR |= _BV(SPIE); // SPI interrupt enabled
}

ISR(SPI_STC_vect) {
  // Interrupt Service Routine(SPI_(SPI Transfer Complete)_vector)
  byte c = SPDR;
  // SPDR = SPI Data Register, so you are saving the byte of information in that register to byte c
  if (pos < sizeof buf) {
    buf[pos++] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
      process_it = true;
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (process_it = true) {
    Serial.println(buf);
    pos = 0;
    process_it = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Stick the float value in a buffer and send the bytes over SPI. On the receiving end, read the bytes into a char array and read that as a float.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what I needed to do and I wanted to post my finished code. I also added an ability to transfer more than one float value.

Master:

```
#include <SPI.h>

float a = 3.14;
float b = 2.25;
uint8_t storage [12];
float buff[2] = {a, b};
void setup()
{
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  SPI.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV8);
}

void loop()
{

  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);
  memcpy(storage, &buff, 8);
  Serial.print("storage[0] = "); Serial.println(storage[0]); // the 
  following serial prints were to check i was getting the right decimal 
  numbers for the floats.
  Serial.print("storage[1] = "); Serial.println(storage[1]);
  Serial.print("storage[2] = "); Serial.println(storage[2]);
  Serial.print("storage[3] = "); Serial.println(storage[3]);
  Serial.print("storage[4] = "); Serial.println(storage[4]);
  Serial.print("storage[5] = "); Serial.println(storage[5]);
  Serial.print("storage[6] = "); Serial.println(storage[6]);
  Serial.print("storage[7] = "); Serial.println(storage[7]);
  SPI.transfer(storage, sizeof storage ); //SPI library allows a user to 
  transfer a whole array of bytes and you need to include the size of the 
  array.
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
}
```

For my Slave code:

```
#include <SPI.h>

byte storage [8];
volatile byte pos;
volatile boolean process;
float buff[2];

void setup()
{
  pinMode(MISO,OUTPUT);
  SPCR |= _BV(SPE);
  SPCR |= _BV(SPIE);
  pos = 0;
  process = false;
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

ISR(SPI_STC_vect)
{
  byte gathered = SPDR;
  if( pos < sizeof storage)
    {
      storage[pos++] = gathered;
    }
    else 
    process = true;
}

void loop()
{
  if( process )
  {
    Serial.print("storage[0] = "); Serial.println(storage[0]);
    Serial.print("storage[1] = "); Serial.println(storage[1]);
    Serial.print("storage[2] = "); Serial.println(storage[2]);
    Serial.print("storage[3] = "); Serial.println(storage[3]);
    Serial.print("storage[4] = "); Serial.println(storage[4]);
    Serial.print("storage[5] = "); Serial.println(storage[5]);
    Serial.print("storage[6] = "); Serial.println(storage[6]);
    Serial.print("storage[7] = "); Serial.println(storage[7]);
    memcpy(buff,&storage,8);
    Serial.print("This is buff[0]");Serial.println(buff[0]);
    Serial.print("This is buff[1]");Serial.println(buff[1]);
    storage[pos] = 0;
    pos = 0;
    process = false;


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that Serial.print doesn't know what to do with a byte array. Either declare it as a char array or cast it in the print statement:

```
char buf[7];
```

OR

```
Serial.print((char*) buf);
```

Either way, though, it's not going to show up as a float like you want.

An easier way to do all this is to use memcpy or a union to go back and forth between float and bytes. On the master end:

```
uint8_t buf[4];
memcpy(buf, &a, 4);
```

Then use SPI to send 4 bytes. Reverse it on the peripheral end.

Note that sending '\n' as the termination byte is a bad idea because it can lead to weird behavior, since one of the bytes in the float could easily be 0x0a, the hexadecimal equivalent of '\n'.

Comment: Im not sure how to implement what you have told me. I looked up the commands and what they mean but I dont per se know exactly how it should look or works. Can I expand what you have told me to later transfer an array of floats? I apologize for commenting so late as school has kept me busy.